# Banco de dados SQL Recovery Mode

Tags: sql-server

Boa tarde,
Uma base de dados esta com status "In Recovery".
Ao tentar analizar o log de erro atraves deste comando dbcc checkdb, retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro.

Database is beeing recovered. Wait until recovery is finished.

Isso significa que o proprio SQL Server esta restaurando o banco de dados automaticamente?

CONFIRMADO: O SQL inicia e finaliza o processo de recuperação por conta própria. E o banco de dados fica inacessível nesse período.

Agora estou com um problema maior. O serviço do SQL esta consumindo muita memória e esta muito lento no tempo de resposta para efetuar um select simples.

E sempre que tento reiniciar o servidor, o banco de dados volta em modo recovery.

Tentei verificar a lista de processos pendentes, utilizando SP_WHO2, e tem apenas dois processos de CHECKPOINT que aparecem constantemente.

O servidor esta ocioso, sem uso.

Esse problema ocorreu apos o servidor reiniciar durante um processo que alterava uma tabela de 70 milhões de registros.

Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Consegue olhar qual o tamanho do arquivo de log do seu banco?

Comment: O banco tem 330 GB. O LOG 80 GB. Espaço livre em HD é de 1TB.

Comment: Tenta fazer um backup completo pra limpar o arquivo de log

Answer (score 1):

Segundo essa [resposta do DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9064):

Está rodando o [Crash Recovery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.logging.aspx), causas possíveis:

1. SQL Server reiniciou manualmente, devido a um crash ou start/stop do servidor
2. Um erro grave aconteceu no banco de dados, forçando ele a desligar pra recuperar
3. Alguem usou o comando `RESTORE WITH RECOVERY`
4. A [opcao de auto-fechamento](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249.aspx) está configurada, causando o desligamento do banco quando o ultimo usuario sai, e causando um reinicio quando o proximo usuario conecta.

Te recomendo ler a resposta em ingles, mas acho que isso ai ja ajuda :)

Se está demorando muito pra recuperar e nao parece ter atividade, talvez voce tenha que restaurar pelos backups. E se ta com coragem, da uma lida em [como recuperar/reparar databases suspeitas](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/TechEd-Demo-Creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database.aspx).

Comment: obrigado. O banco voltou sozinho. Mas esta com problemas de lentidão.